# How to make sure that servlet is not loaded?

Tags: java, servlets

I have servlet in my web.xml but i don't want my application to load it, one would think that if we don't want that servlet to load then what is the purpose of putting it there, actually I need to have it in web.xml because am deploying two instances of application and on one instance I need to have that servlet and on another I do not want to have it and I'm using only one `web.xml`, am not sure how this can be done.

Here is my `web.xml`:

```
 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>StartServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.web.startServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
```

I cannot put `-ve` value because then container would invoke this servlet randomly, kindly correct me here and advise of an proper way to do it.

Comment: @Tomasz: Thanks for updating my post. I tend to eat up some stuffs while thinking.

Comment: -Ve voter, please advise so that quality of question can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the Servlet (which means that it will not be reachable through defined url-pattern mapping) by using `enabled` element in web.xml.

[Servlets 3.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) in *Chapter 8.2.3 Assembling the descriptor from web.xml, web-fragment.xml and annotations* says:

> (...)
>   3. If a servlet is disabled using the enabled element introduced in the web.xml
>       then the servlet will not be available at the url-pattern specified for the servlet. (...)

The `enabled` element is defined in XML Schema [here](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-common_3_0.xsd) and can be found as a child element of the `<servlet>` element.

Comment: I believe, this one is only for `Servlet 3.0`, one question that arise in here is how can i find what servlet version application is using? I have `jboss version 4`

Comment: Yup, sorry for not mentioning it. You can find it out on JBoss website (you know - *somewhere* on their website...) but I'm pretty sure that it's pre-servlets 3.0... You can also check your `web.xml` file for `version` attribute. The value of this attribute explicitly defines what Servlets version are you using.

Answer (score 1):

`<load-on-startup>` allows you to configure lazy-loading. By default the servlet is loaded only when it is accessed (by its url-pattern). You can set it to be loaded on startup instead.

Comment: I have url pattern set to `/*` and so don't have that constraint.

Comment: it's not a constraint. You either have your servlet loaded on startup, or the first time a request is sent.

Comment: Agree. But is there a way by which I can make sure that StartServlet is not accessed on one instance and can be accessed on another?

Comment: How can i set it up to load on startup

Comment: you can't. Unless you change the web.xml file

Comment: setting the load-on-startup value to 0 or positive number means it is loaded on startup

Comment: I don't know your exact parameters. But usually you provide some external configuration (and set it with `-Dsomeparam` to tomcat). But if you run the same app twice on the same tomcat - you can't do anything

Comment: Is there example, I can look up for similar kind of scenario for my application am using JBoss

Answer (score 0):

> `<load-on-startup>` allows you to configure lazy-loading. By default the servlet is loaded only when it is accessed (by its url-pattern). You can set it to be loaded on startup instead.

That said, if you set the servlet that isn't supposed to load to only load on request, and then use a load balancer to ensure that whatever URL would hit that server hits the other one instead, you'd probably be good to go.

+1 to Bozho. His answer is a great place to start.