# What is the meaning of <enabled>false</enabled> for a servlet definition in web.xml?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, websphere, weblogic

Seems that web.xml for a servlet has an element called

```
<enabled>false</enabled>
```

that can be put in the servelt definition like so

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</servlet>
```

Does enabled refer to the ability of the servlet to process requests? I noticed that even if I set enabled to false the init method of the the servelt gets called. Searching through the servlet spec pdf did not provide an explanation of the meaning of <enabled> in fact I could not even find the string <enabled> in the servlet 3.0 spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Java Servlet 3.0 specification, 8.2.3 section 3 [(see the pdf)](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf):

> If a servlet is disabled using the **enabled element** introduced in the web.xml
>   then the servlet will not be available at the url-pattern specified for the servlet.

**Edit:** Here's another post on this exact topic: [How to make sure that servlet is not loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512197/how-to-make-sure-that-servlet-is-not-loaded)

**Edit 2:** (putting summary from comments below in here)
In Tomcat 7 (as of 7.0.25) it appears that the Servlet *will* initialize but requests to its url-pattern will respond with a **status code 503** (`SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE`)

Comment: The above statement is ambiguous does it mean that the servelt does not get initialized or just that it is not mapped and therefore should not be sent any requests? For example I have the load-on-startup element which beans that the servelt should be started when the app starts. In my case I want a servlet that starts on application startup, but without any url mapping because I am using that servlet to run some self tests on the app to make sure the environment is configured correctly for the app.

Comment: From the tomcat 7 source, if disabled this way, it looks like it returns true for `isUnavailable()` (search [this page](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_25/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardWrapper.java) for "enabled" and [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_25/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContextValve.java) for `isUnavailable`) --> WHICH MEANS --> it _probably_ gets initialized but any requests to its url will return errors.

Comment: I can confirm that it does initialize it (again, in Tomcat 7 specifically): note that `initServlet` in `StandardWrapper` ([see source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_25/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardWrapper.java)) does not consider the `enabled` state.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find it anywhere indeed, apart from the XSD. If it still handles requests (check that), then I guess it is added there for future use, or to let containers decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Look at Oracle web.xml deployment descriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039287)

Seems that this is server specific entry, what kind of application server are you using?

Comment: I am using Tomcat 7.x, the servlet 3.0 spec mentions the enabled attribute in the context of explaining how a final war is put together from multiple fragments, and the screen shots of the XML have it but there is no explanation for the element on its own. Also any element in web.xml is applicable to all app servers, so enabled must be a generic setting.